# Распознование голоса при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: python, python-3.x, распознавание-речи

У меня есть такой код:

```
#voice to text beta 1
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio,keyboard

r = sr.Recognizer()

def main():
    try: talk()

    except(UnboundLocalError):
        pass
    except(TypeError):
        pass

def talk():
    global text
    text = ''
    with sr.Microphone() as sourse:
        print('Я вас слушаю: ')
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(sourse)
        audio = r.listen(sourse)
        
        try:text = (r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU")).lower()  
        except:print("error") 

        print(text)

keyboard.add_hotkey('p', main)
input()
```

При его запуске, и нажатии на букву p происходит распознование голоса, но если отпустить кнопку, то все равно оно продолжится пока окончательно не дослушает слово.
Как сделать что-бы при нажатии на букву, началось распознование голоса, а при отпускании оно прекращалось?

Comment: Ловите `key realesed` - это отпускание кнопки, и дальше с ним работайте

Comment: @Стас Это мне ничего не дает. Я не знаю как работает остановка распознавание речи.

Comment: Оно само останавливает запись с микрофона по "тишине"(но это не точно). Не всегда точно определеят конец фразы, возможно мешают посторонние звуки и программа "думает", что фраза еще звучит. В вашем случае можно записать аудио с микрофона в wav формате, а затем готовый файл отправлять гуглу. Запись с микрофона можно контролировать по событию. Работа с микрофоном производиться с помощью модуля pyaudio, запись аудио файла с помощью модуля wave.

Answer (score 0):

Можно взять вот этот код за основу:

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import audioop
import time

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 16000
RECORD_SECONDS = 10
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []
min_level = 3100#"уровень" громкости ниже которого звучит "тишина"(нужно подбирать под каждый микрофон)
'''
#цикл для проверки уровня(2 - это ширина, можно выбирать 1,2,3,4)
for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    print(audioop.max(data,2))
'''
wait_time = time.time() + 3#это время означает, что после наступления "тишины" нужно подождать 3 секунды и завершить запись
wait_timeout = time.time() + 15#это время означает, что общая длительность записи не превышает 15 секунд
while time.time() < wait_time and time.time() < wait_timeout:#сюда вставляются любые условия - нажатие или отжатие клавиш
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)#читаю данные с микрофона
    frames.append(data)#кидаю их в список
    if audioop.max(data,2) > min_level:#пересчитываю условия выполнения цикла в зависимости от уровня громкости
        wait_time = time.time() + 3


print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

#далее этот код сохраняет аудиофайл
wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```